# How to add events in SVG "use" DOM trees?

Tags: javascript, events, svg, d3.js

I would like to have two (almost) identical inline SVG graphics with events (which I add during creation with d3). The second element is created after the first is finished (completely with bindings and stuff) like this:

```
d3.select("#part2")
        .append("svg")
        .append("use")
            .attr("xlink:href", "#myfirstelement");
```

Basically I thought this should do the job. But it doesn't react in any way and to fix this, I would probably need to add (and sync) it seperately. Any chance to avoid this?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/uCSE5/

Comment: *"But it doesn't react in any way"*: Do you mean that event handlers are not triggered? Since it is a UI issue, please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: Exactly. I created a fiddle with the problem. The second, cloned rectangle should be clickable, too.

Comment: Which browser are you using? It seems to work for me in Chrome.

Comment: FF 17.0.1, and you're right, it works in chrome :(

Comment: edit: and every other browser except IE, too.. seems to be a firefox bug.

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=265895 and not even a new one.

Comment: Well, these are not good news for you, but at least we know that it is a known problem.